# inconsistent application of deletion of "uncivil" comments

Tags: discussion, moderation

dunno who the moderators are but the deletion of my comments in [this thread](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/328001/is-power-of-two-bits-per-word-convenient-if-it-is-why-is-that) coupled with the retention of similarly disrespectful comments from *gnasher729* appears to show favoritism, or at least, insufficient reading/consideration or awareness of the comments as a whole in that thread.

i'm not particularly put-out, but i think the admins or moderators of this forum should be aware of the disparate scrutiny applied to contentious comments in this particular case.

Comment: I am not a moderator, and I don't know exactly what you wrote (and I guess don't want to know), but whatever it was, I think you take this too personal. Welcome to the world of public internet forums - flaming and flame wars have a "long tradition" here.

Comment: @DocBrown they say [Stack Exchange is hard to troll](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a0jCv.png)

Comment: well, @DocBrown, it's more the inconsistency that i am bringing up.

Comment: The politic on stackoverflow is not very fair (this moderator seems very nice compared to many other). I tried to reason with some moderators and it became very boring (since I can be extremely detailed in reporting when someone make a mistake). They are humans. We all do mistakes. The stupid thing (in administering communities in this way) is always pretending to be right.

Answer (score 5):

If there are certain keywords in comments then a single flag is all that's needed to delete that comment, so it could be that.

If your comments showed up in the flag queue a diamond moderator would have deleted them, but perhaps didn't check the other comments. If that's the case I apologise on behalf of us all. However, if there are a number of flags that indicate an argument in comments we usually do check the rest of the comments as well.

However, if you think that a comment is inappropriate, don't respond, just flag it for one of us to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

> for someone with 8801 rep, this answer is quite ignorant.
>
> -
>
> @gnasher729, you are totally ignorant of both the history and the hardware involved in the history.

These are the couple of comments that were flagged and deleted. When I removed them, I took a (quick) look for other comments that were mere personal attacks devoid of any actual (technical) argument or other useful information. I didn't find any. If there were - or appeared later - feel free to flag them.

Comment: *"@robertbristow-johnson: Total lack of imagination ..."*

Comment: *" Could you extend the paragraph or maybe provide a link explaining the basics?"* – Andreas  (regarding an answer from Martin Maat) 

*"It's nonsense..."*  – gnasher729

Comment: Use your flags @robert.

Comment: i think i did..

Answer (score 2):

Comments only have two sanctioned purposes: *clarification of the on-topic material of a post,* and *asking for such clarification*.  Any other use subjects them to removal.

Beyond that, a good moderator will refrain from taking any action at all unless the community shows some interest with their flags.

In this particular case, I see several comments that are either unnecessary, obsolete or just plain noise, and I plan on flagging several of them.  In particular, the debate over whether the question is a duplicate or not.  The remainder of the comments continue to be too lengthy because certain people would rather get into a debate instead of accepting some facts that were presented in the comments that are not only factual but obvious.

Even then, content like that more properly belongs in an answer and not a comment.  I tried posting such an answer, but it wasn't received well and the participants seem more interested in engaging in pedantry than accepting the obvious.